# How do I bind .sh files to keyboard combination?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

Just wondering; how do I bind .sh files to run when I press a particular key combination? (like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>)

Thanks,

Dante

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the keyboard shortcuts interface to do this. Remember to add the full path.
[image]

Comment: To clarify, tildes are not expanded.

Answer (score 4):

Goto System>>Preferences>>Keyboard Shortcuts

It will open a window click **add**
[image]

After clicking add it will show you a window with Name and Command.You can write any name there and in command you should give the full path of the file with bash in-front **bash /path/to/the/file.sh**

[image]

After adding the Name & Command.You can assign the shortcut key.

Comment: how to run the script which needs sudo permission inside ?

Answer (score 3):

`xbindkeys` allows you to saves multiple configurations (if you want that flexibility).

Also `xbindkeys` gives you **many** more key-combinations, because it **(optionally)** allows you to make **Numlock**, **ScrollLock**, and **CapsLock** states significant...

Another feature which is **not** found in *Keboard Shortcuts* is that you **can** use `~/` and `$HOME/` for your home directory, instead of having to hard-code it.

To install **xbindkeys**, and **xbindkeys-config** (the GUI for xbindkeys)

```
sudo apt-get install xbindkeys xbindkeys-config
```

To create the default config file for xbindkeys

```
xbindkeys --defaults > $HOME/.xbindkeysrc
```

Then run:

```
xbindkeys
xbindkeys-config
```

And for your first keybinding, you may find it useful to assign <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, or whatever you prefer, to `xbindkeys-config`

To keep the xbindkeys hotkeys active ever time you start the computer...

```
Main Menu
  System  
    Preferences  
      Startup Applications  
        [ Add ]  
          Name:     xbindkeys  
          Command:  xbindkeys  
          Comment:  xbindkeys
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness: If you are using Compiz you can set custom keyboard and mouse shortcuts using CCSM (Compiz Config Settings Manager) and the Commands plugin.

Just put in the name of your sh-script (for example "CustomScript" in the attached screenshot) and give it a custom key binding in the *Key Bindings* tab. Your script needs to be placed in a directory that is monitored by Ubuntu for this to work. I do place all of my scripts in the `/usr/local/bin` directory.

Make sure that your script is executable by applying `chmod +x CustomScript` in a terminal and note that all words are case sensitive.

Compiz allows to export all settings including shortcuts which is very useful for settings up similar machines.

[image: (see screenshot)]