# Can I set Hot Corners to run custom commands in Unity?

Tags: unity, scripts, unity-tweak-tool

I really like Hot Corners. :-)

Is it somehow possible to run a custom command on a hot corner as shown below?

[image]

Comment: I don't think it's possible with hotcorners specifically ( at least not with the way Unity uses them), but it is possible to trigger scripts when mouse is placed in specific area of screen. For instance, see http://askubuntu.com/a/758307/295286 , Mouse over action section.   I'll look more into hotcorners, but if those won't work out, is custom script OK ?

Comment: Multi-monitor or single?

Comment: Hi orschiro, posted. Please mention if all is clear (or not).

Comment: Hey, I see there are more hotcorners here than in my answer. How many would you prefer?

Comment: Hi @orschiro . I made an indicator to match the functionality you requested. Please try it out, let me know how it works for you, and whether you have any additional feature requests

Comment: I think CCSM can do this. (I'm not at my PC rn.)

Comment: @wjandrea CCSM indeed can perform some mouse actions, there is a list of them under General Options -> Keybindings, but I've not seen any setting for custom commands there.

Comment: @wjandrea I very much doubt that, ccsm simply sets options, dconf has options like `scale` and  `show-desktop-edge`, no custom commands for hotcorners.

Comment: @JacobVlijm, Serg, See my answer.

Comment: @wjandrea yeah, so sad that you are right. Kidding, great answer!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### CCSM

1. Install CompizConfig Settings Manager (CCSM). Run in terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
   ```
2. Open CCSM.
3. Go to "Commands"
4. Enter your desired command in one of the slots. E.g:

   [image: CCSM screenshot - command]
5. Go to "Edge Bindings" tab
6. Click "None" and set your desired hot corner (or edge), which corresponds to the command you just set

   [image: CCSM screenshot - hot corners]
7. Move your mouse to the corner
8. Now your command is run!

   [image: CCSM screenshot - command running]

Confirmed working on 14.04.

Comment: Easiest of all proposed solutions. If command desired in better realized thru a script than just make the compiz command point to that script or just scriptname if script is in a bin folder in $PATH. Only possible downside is unity/compiz has been known to randomly  'lose' user set commands, i.e., those that aren't integrated. How to integrate a user command is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: @wjandrea So it is implemented after all.  Compiz doesnt seize to amaze me. Good answer, most fitting for what OP seeks.  +1'ed

Comment: Unfortunately, you are right,  haha. Yes exactly what OP asked for.

Comment: You've helped me out quite a few times with your edits and answers. Have a "cookie" as ole'Serg used to say... indeed have half a dozen :)

Answer (score 6):

#### Custom commands

If you are using Unity *and* have ccsm installed, wjandrea's answer is your answer of course. *If not*, or to use on other distros, a light weight alternative might be useful.

With the script below, you can set *any* command, specific to each of your hotcorners.

As an example, I made the following setup:

- Top Left         ***No action***
- Top Right        ***Run Gedit***
- Bottom Left      ***No action***
- Bottom RightRun  ***Gnome-terminal***

Of course you can also make the commands run external scripts.

Furthermore, you can set the *size* of the hot corner in the line:

```
cornersize = 10
```

Simply change the value (pixels). The script sets (square) areas to trigger your commands:

[image]

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time

cornersize = 20

commands = [
    None,
    "gedit",
    None,
    "gnome-terminal",
    ]

def get(cmd):
    return subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8").strip()

def get_pos():
    return [int(s.split(":")[1]) for s in get(["xdotool", "getmouselocation"]).split()[:2]]

scrdata = get("xrandr").split(); resindex = scrdata.index("connected")+2
res = [int(n) for n in scrdata[resindex].split("+")[0].split("x")]

match1 = None

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    xy = get_pos()
    x = xy[0]; y = xy[1]
    test = [
        [x < cornersize, y < cornersize],
        [x > res[0]-cornersize, y < cornersize],
        [x < cornersize, y > res[1]-cornersize],
        [x > res[0]-cornersize, y > res[1]-cornersize],
        ]
    match2 = [i for i, p in enumerate(test) if all(p)]
    if match2 != match1:
        if match2:
            cmd = commands[match2[0]]
            if cmd:
                subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd])
    match1 = match2
```

#### Set up

1. The script needs `xdotool`

   ```
   sudo apt install xdotool
   ```
2. Copy the script into an empty file, save i as `hotcorners2.py`
3. In the head of the script, set your commands (mind the quotes)

   ```py
   commands = [
       None,
       "gedit",
       None,
       "gnome-terminal",
   ]
   ```

   (subsequently top left/righ, bottom left/right)
4. Test- run the script:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/hotcorners2.py
   ```
5. If all works fine, add to Startup Applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add. Add the command:

   ```
   /bin/bash -c "sleep 5 && python3 /path/to/hotcorners2.py"
   ```

#### Notes

- The script currently runs on on (the first) screen. It can be easily edited to take care of multiple screens, even do different things in different screens, please mention.
- If a few people like it, we can add a gui and a ppa for convenient usage and easy installation.

---

### EDIT

If we use a bit more advanced computing, we can use a *radius* instead of a square area to trigger the commands (thanks to good old @pythagoras):

[image]

Small difference, but just for fun:

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import math
import time

# set distance (hotcorner sensitivity)
radius = 20

# top-left, top-right, bottom-left, bottom-right
commands = [
    None,
    "gedit",
    None,
    "gnome-terminal",
    ]

def get(cmd):
    return subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8").strip()

def get_pos():
    return [int(s.split(":")[1]) for s in get(["xdotool", "getmouselocation"]).split()[:2]]

# get the resolution
scrdata = get("xrandr").split(); resindex = scrdata.index("connected")+2
res = [int(n) for n in scrdata[resindex].split("+")[0].split("x")]
# list the corners, could be more elegant no doubt
corners = [[0, 0], [res[0], 0], [0, res[1]], [res[0], res[1]]]

match1 = None

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    pos = get_pos()
    # get the current difference from the mousepointer to each of the corner (radius)
    diff = [int(math.sqrt(sum([(c[i]-pos[i])**2 for i, n in enumerate(res)])))\
            for c in corners]
    # see if any of the corners is "approached" within the radius
    match2 = [diff.index(n) for n in diff if n < radius]
    # if so, and the corresponding command is not set to None, run it.
    if all([match2 != match1, match2]):
        cmd = commands[match2[0]]
        if cmd:
            subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd])
    match1 = match2
```

#### Usage

Is pretty much the same. Set your commands, and the radius to trigger, in the head section of the script.

Answer (score 5):

#### NOTE:

[wjandrea's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/884851/295286)  is the most suitable answer for someone who uses default Ubuntu or Ubuntu Kylin ( or has compiz as their display manager ), thus it gets my upvote and respect. The answer provided below, can be used on Unity as well, but probably would be slightly redundant. However, on desktop environments that don't have compiz, one can use the indicator presented below. I've tested it briefly in Lubuntu 16.04 VM , so I know it works there, and made it compatible with Kylin 14.04 as well. For GNOME and MATE desktops, you will need have support for AppIndicators enabled first in order to use any indicator.

#### Introduction

I've implemented `indicator-edger` which allows triggering user-defined commands based on mouse position anywhere along the 4 edges of the screen. Original version was done within one day, in approximately 7 hours, thus it is fairly minimalistic but does the job.

[image]

The indicator is controlled via `~/.edger-commands.json` file , obviously in `json` format. It can be written manually by the user, or set via indicator's `DEFINE COMMANDS` option. The enable/disable triggering option is remembered and written automatically to file for user's convenience. Sample configuration file would be like so:

```
{
    "right": "gnome-terminal",
    "top": "firefox",
    "left": "",
    "bottom": "gnome-screenshot",
    "enabled": true
}
```

Note the `"left"` entry in the file. That edge is unset, but due to `json` syntax it requires having an empty string there, i.e. quotes `""`.

Once the indicator detects that user has placed the mouse along any of the edges (with ~3 pixel margin), the indicator will send a bubble notification and run the appropriate command (if defined). Activation of the trigger won't repeat unless the user moves the mouse away from the edge.

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot above, the indicator also has debugging output in the command-line. If you find any bugs, feel free to run it from the terminal, find out what error occurs, and submit appropriate bug report on [issues page of the project's GitHub](https://github.com/SergKolo/indicator-edger/issues).

Currently there is no support for corners (only edges) and it was built for one-monitor setup (obviously, one cannot cover all the bases within 7 hours of creation), but those features might be available eventually in the future.

#### Installation and source code

The source code is available at the projects [GitHub](https://github.com/SergKolo/indicator-edger) page or via [Launchpad](https://code.launchpad.net/~1047481448-2/+archive/ubuntu/sergkolo). Installation is performed via the following commands in terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:1047481448-2/sergkolo
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-edger
```