# Unity launcher reveal pressure

Tags: unity

is it possible to desactivate Unity launcher reveal pressure on Ubuntu 14.10.
Even if I set up the reveal pressure at 0, it is still not sensitive enough and I must try several time with the mouse pointer before it appears.

Answer (score 0):

Try settings the "edge responsiveness" to maximum, for example from the command line using

```
gsettings set org.compiz.unityshell:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/ edge-responsiveness 8.0
```

or with [Unsettings](http://www.florian-diesch.de/software/unsettings/) in the "Launcher" tab.

Comment: edge responsiveness is already at the maximum

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem, but in Ubuntu 16.04. Finally I found solution in Compiz. Set launch reveal pressure to 1. Hope it will help to somebody still. See the image:

[image: CCSM screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using mouse for reveal pressure, [bind the script](https://askubuntu.com/q/15050/295286) below to a shortcut. It will allow you toggling unity launcher at will

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
schema="org.compiz.unityshell"
path="/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/"
key="launcher-hide-mode"

current_value=$(gsettings get "$schema":"$path" "$key")

if [ $current_value -eq 0 ] ;
then
    gsettings set "$schema":"$path" "$key" 1
else
    gsettings set "$schema":"$path" "$key" 0
fi
```

Comment: The super key reveals the launcher (in 16.04 at least)

Comment: @AndyP  Yes, that is so,  and it can be disabled via several methods listed here: https://askubuntu.com/q/105558/295286 or  one can use a script to target particular use cases like   https://askubuntu.com/a/805833/295286   
   This particular question asked only about the mouse pressure, hence the answer matches it accordingly, nothing more nor less