# Turn off SUPER key during fullscreen apps

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, fullscreen

Is there a way to turn off the SUPER key during gaming sessions or fullscreen apps in general?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. I will begin writing a script for that shortly and will post once I have it working

Comment: that would be awesome!

Comment: Answer posted, let me know what you think

Comment: **Note to future visitors** I have previously written a related script, for disabling Super key per specific window. Please check it out if you're interested : http://askubuntu.com/q/754884/295286

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Introduction

The following script disables <kbd>Super</kbd> key if any X11 window is in fullscreen mode. It is meant to be added as a startup application , but also can run in a stand-alone mode.

#### Usage

To run the script manually it is sufficient to do :

```
python disable_super_key.py
```

In order to make the scrip start automatically upon login, consult [How do I start applications automatically on login?](https://askubuntu.com/q/48321/295286)

#### Obtaining the script source code

One could copy the script source from this answer, or obtain it via cloning my [GitHub](https://github.com/SergKolo/sergrep) repository.

Instructions for those who have `git` :

1. `cd /opt`
2. `sudo git clone https://github.com/SergKolo/sergrep.git`
3. `chmod -R +x sergrep`

The script will be located in `/opt/sergrep/disable_super_key.py`

#### Script source code

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
###########################################################
# Author: Serg Kolo , contact: 1047481448@qq.com 
# Date: August 1st , 2016
# Purpose: Disable Super key that calls Unity Dash, when any 
#          X11 window is in fullscreen state
# 
# Written for: https://askubuntu.com/q/805807/295286
# Tested on: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 
###########################################################
# Copyright: Serg Kolo , 2016
#    
#     Permission to use, copy, modify, and distribute this software is hereby granted
#     without fee, provided that  the copyright notice above and this permission statement
#     appear in all copies.
#
#     THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
#     IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
#     FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.  IN NO EVENT SHALL
#     THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
#     LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
#     FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER
#     DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
from __future__ import print_function
import gi
gi.require_version('Gdk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import  Gdk,Gio
import subprocess
import signal
import time
import sys

debug = False

def gsettings_get(schema,path,key):
    """ fetches value of gsettings schema"""
    if path is None:
        gsettings = Gio.Settings.new(schema)
    else:
        gsettings = Gio.Settings.new_with_path(schema,path)
    return gsettings.get_value(key)

def gsettings_set(schema,path,key,value):
    """ sets value of gsettings schema """
    if path is None:
        gsettings = Gio.Settings.new(schema)
    else:
        gsettings = Gio.Settings.new_with_path(schema,path)
    return gsettings.set_string(key,value)


def gsettings_reset(schema,path,key):
    """ resets schema:key value to default"""
    if path is None:
        gsettings = Gio.Settings.new(schema)
    else:
        gsettings = Gio.Settings.new_with_path(schema,path)
    return gsettings.reset(key)

def run_cmd(cmdlist):
    """ reusable function for running shell commands"""
    try:
        stdout = subprocess.check_output(cmdlist)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        pass
    else:
        if stdout:
            return stdout


def main():
    """ defines entry point of the program """
    screen = Gdk.Screen.get_default()
    while True:

        key_state = str(gsettings_get('org.compiz.unityshell', 
                                  '/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/', 
                                  'show-launcher'))
        active_xid = str(screen.get_active_window().get_xid())
        wm_state =  run_cmd( ['xprop', '-root', '-notype','-id',active_xid, '_NET_WM_STATE'])  

        if debug : print(key_state,wm_state)

        if 'FULLSCREEN' in wm_state:
            if "Super" in  key_state:    
                gsettings_set('org.compiz.unityshell', 
                              '/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/',
                              'show-launcher', 
                              'Disabled')

        else:
            if "Disabled" in key_state :
               gsettings_reset( 'org.compiz.unityshell', 
                                '/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/',
                                'show-launcher')


        time.sleep(0.25)


def sigterm_handler(*args):
    """ ensures that Super key has been reset upon exit"""
    gsettings_reset( 'org.compiz.unityshell', 
                     '/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/',
                     'show-launcher')

    if debug: print('CAUGHT SIGTERM')
    sys.exit(0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM,sigterm_handler)
    main()
```

#### Debugging

In case debugging is necessary , change line 32 from `debug = False` to `debug = True` and run the script from command line

Comment: I have been asked to make this script work per specific workspace. For those interested , you can find the solution here http://askubuntu.com/a/816512/295286 NOTE also that this script has been updated to handle termination of the script to re-enable SUPER key once the script exits