# My keyboard shortcut binding does not work with my script

Tags: 12.04, bash

I was trying to bind a keyboard shortcut to my script. I tried binding it to keyboard shortcut from

```
System Settings>Keyboard>Shortcuts>Add Shortcut
```

I added new shortcut and as mentioned in [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1540961) link I tried to add 
`bash /path/to/my/script` in the command section of the new shortcut. The permission is right.

It runs when I run from terminal.

I tried binding it using compiz-config-settings as mentioned in [the answer given by n3rd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15050/how-do-i-bind-sh-files-to-keyboard-combination). But it did not work.

[this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10873457/) is my script.

Comment: [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10873457/) is my pastebin code

Comment: Just worked it out :) Might wanna delete comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `more` doesn't seem to work.

Try changing each time it says `more` to `cat`.

---

How did I solve it?

I added this line after each if:

```
notify-send Alert No1
```

changing the number 1 to another number each time I used it. This showed me that the `if then else` statements weren't running. I then decided to change it to `cat`, because I use that and know it works!

```
notify-send
```

is a useful debugging tool for me. Have a look at it's man page to make it easier to use. If you can't use it, try to `echo sometextNo1 > logfile.txt`, and check that file.