# Why does the more command not work when bound to a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: command-line, bash, shortcut-keys, cat

I have two commands that both work in terminal:

```
notify-send "$(more /home/tim/autest.sh | head -1)"
```

and

```
notify-send "$(cat /home/tim/autest.sh | head -1)"
```

putting them in a script like this:

```
#! /bin/bash

notify-send "$(more /home/tim/autest.sh | head -1)"

notify-send "$(cat /home/tim/autest.sh | head -1)"
```

still gives two outputs, but only one is the actual correct output:

More:

[image]

Cat:

[image]

When I run from the terminal, they both show the correct output. Why is this? Why does more not give the correct output when triggered from a keyboard shortcut?

Note that this is not an issue with `notify-send`, it does the same thing when echoing to a log file:

```
#! /bin/bash

echo $(more /home/tim/autest.sh | head -1) > log1.txt

echo $(cat /home/tim/autest.sh | head -1) > log2.txt
```

Log1:

```
::::::::::::::
```

Log2:

```
#! /bin/bash
```

Comment: Works correctly for me, the two log files are exactly the same. Do you have some strange conf file/environment variable  for  `more`? (BTW, why not just `head -1 /home/tim/autest.sh`?)

Comment: @Rmano I'm asking because of this question + solution... http://askubuntu.com/questions/612979/my-keyboard-shortcut-binding-does-not-work-with-my-script/612991#612991

Comment: Does it work if you add `-1` parameter to more ? It's supposed to limit screen size to one line

Comment: still the `::::::::::::::`

Comment: Post the content of `/home/tim/autest.sh`.

Comment: @A.B. I have. The 2 code blocks that start `#! /bin/bash`. It references itself.

Comment: @Tim Yes, same problem here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this command:

```
notify-send "$(more /home/tim/autest.sh | head -4 | tail -1)"
```

When you use your script with a shortcut, `more` gives this:

```
::::::::::::::
/home/tim/autest.sh
::::::::::::::
#! /bin/bash
```

Here is an excerpt from the source code of `more.c`

```
while (fnum < nfiles) {
  if ((f = checkf (fnames[fnum], &clearit)) != NULL) {
      context.line = context.chrctr = 0;
      Currline = 0;
      if (firstf) sigsetjmp (restore, 1);
      if (firstf) {
        firstf = 0;
        if (srchopt) {
            search (initbuf, f, 1);
            if (noscroll)
              left--;
        }
        else if (initopt)
            skiplns (initline, f);
      }
      else if (fnum < nfiles && !no_tty) {
        sigsetjmp (restore, 1);
        left = command (fnames[fnum], f);
      }
      if (left != 0) {
        if ((noscroll || clearit) && (file_size != LONG_MAX)) {
            if (clreol)
              home ();
            else
              doclear ();
        }
        if (prnames) {
            if (bad_so)
              erasep (0);
            if (clreol)
              cleareol ();
            putsout("::::::::::::::");
            if (promptlen > 14)
              erasep (14);
            putchar('\n');
            if(clreol) cleareol();
            puts(fnames[fnum]);
            if(clreol) cleareol();
            puts("::::::::::::::");
            if (left > Lpp - 4)
              left = Lpp - 4;
        }
        if (no_tty)
            copy_file (f);
        else {
            within++;
            screen(f, left);
            within = 0;
        }
      }
      sigsetjmp (restore, 1);
      fflush(stdout);
      fclose(f);
      screen_start.line = screen_start.chrctr = 0L;
      context.line = context.chrctr = 0L;
  }
  fnum++;
  firstf = 0;
}
```

Comment: Will check at home

Comment: @Tim And how does it look?

Comment: `notify-send "$(more -u /home/tim/autest.sh | head -n 1)"` works!

Comment: @Tim You're confusing me, I think it does not work for you?

Comment: With the -u parameter it gives the correct output!

Comment: @Tim `-u` has nothing to do with ist. I have left in there by mistake.

Comment: @Tim `man more` - "-u     Suppress underlining."

Comment: Ahh, I realise what I changed: `head -n 1` not `head -1`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23174/discussion-between-a-b-and-tim).

Comment: Quoting the GNU source!  :D